# javascript form validation not working and not showing any alerts

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to validate my form in html but it doesn't seem to be working. I feel pretty certain that my code is right. I'm not sure what's going wrong.it's not displaying any alerts.can anyone have idea what is wrong here?thanks in advance.

```
<script>
    function validate() {
        var password2 = document.getElementById("user_password").value;
        var repassword1 = document.getElementById("user_repassword").value;
        var email1 = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
        var atpos = email1.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email1.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (password2.lenght < 7) {
            alert("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
            return false;
        } else if (password2 !== repassword) {
            alert("* Password Does Not Match");
            return false;
        } else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="submitform" method="post" action="signupsuccessfull.php"      onsubmit="return validate(this)" >
   <p id="error_para">* fields are required</p>
   <span id="error_para">*</span> Name:<input type="text" name="name" required  /><br /><br />
   <span id="error_para">*</span> Username:<input type="text" name="username"   required id="field_username"  /><br /><br />
   <span id="error_para">*</span> Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="user_password" required />
   <br /><br />
   <span id="error_para">*</span> Re-Enter Password:<input type="password" name="repassword" id="user_repassword" required /><br /><br />
   <span id="error_para">*</span> Email:<input type="text" name="email" id="user_email" required />
   <br /><br />
   <span id="error_para">*</span> Gender:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required />Male
   &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female<br />
   About Urself:
   <textarea rows="5" cols="18" name="about" ></textarea>
   <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Create Account" name="submit" />
   &nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Cancle" onClick="parent.location='../example/try2.html'"><br /><br /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console of your developer tools? (F12 in most browsers)

Comment: only returning false won't stop the form from being submitted in your example. You should add e.[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to your function.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: repassword is not defined`

Comment: I am using Dreamweavar for coding and i dont think it have any errors  because other code is working fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a2xnvhan/1/

Comment: javascript errors inside a function wont show up unless the code is invoked, so rest of your code will still be working.

Comment: ohk thanx for providing formetted code.i fixed  that error so its now validating for only if password and repassword are matching or not and email address but not chacking for length for password.any suggestion.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using the below code

```
function validate() {

    var password2 = document.getElementById("user_password").value;
    var repassword1 = document.getElementById("user_repassword").value;
    var email1 = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
    var atpos = email1.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email1.lastIndexOf(".");

    var emilPat = /( *?[0-9a-zA-Z] *?){8,}/; 
    var m;
    m = emilPat.exec(password2) 
    if(m== null){
        alert("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
        return false;
    }
    if (password2 !== repassword) {
        alert("* Password Does Not Match");
        return false;
    } else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Buddy it Worked :) ,,

Comment: hey i tested your provided code and its not working for input like jigar12* although its valid and 8 character long.? :(

Answer (score 1):

there are errors in your code. there may be more..

```
if (password2.lenght < 7) {   // length is the right usage
...

} else if (password2 !== repassword) { // it is repassword1 as per you defined.
```

use browser console (developer tools) and find and fix all these issues.

javascript errors inside a function wont show up unless the code is invoked, so rest of your code will still be working.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 typos.

It should be `password2.length`

It should also be `repassword1`, not `repassword` only.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, change the line

```
 if (password2.lenght < 7) {
```

to

```
 if (password2.length < 7) {
```

And  change `repassword` to `repassword1`

Comment: ohk i changed repaasowrd to repassword1 but what is problem with my if(password2.lenght<7) statment.?

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
<script>
    function validate() {
        var password2 = document.getElementById("user_password").value;
        var repassword1 = document.getElementById("user_repassword").value;
        var email1 = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
        var atpos = email1.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email1.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (password2.lenght < 7) {
            alert("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
            return false;
        } else if (password2 != repassword1) {
            alert("* Password Does Not Match");
            return false;
        } else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email1.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```